# Java: JNDI Lookup fails when ran inside a Thread

Tags: java, thread-safety, wildfly, jndi

I'm facing a rather strange behaviour regarding JNDI lookup using Wildfly 18. I have one simple EJB:

```
package com.getronics.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Local(ICalculadoraLocal.class)
public class CalculadoraBean implements ICalculadoraLocal {
        public int suma(int a, int b){
               return a+b;
        }
}
```

With a simple interface:

```
package com.getronics.ejb;

public interface ICalculadoraLocal{
        int suma(int a, int b);
}
```

And a simple JSP page to check it out:

```
<html>
    <body>
            <%@ page import="java.util.Hashtable,javax.naming.*,com.getronics.ejb.*" %>
            request: <%= request.getRequestURI()%><br>
            <%
              final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
              jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
              final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
              ICalculadoraLocal calculadora = (ICalculadoraLocal)context.lookup("java:app/ejb-0.0.0.0.0.1/CalculadoraBean!com.getronics.ejb.ICalculadoraLocal");
              int suma = calculadora.suma(2,2);
                    %>
                    context: <%= context%></br>
                    2+2= <%=suma%>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine:

```
request: /ejb/index.jsp
context: javax.naming.InitialContext@3e532295
2+2= 4
```

However, when I try to use a Thread, like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
            <%@ page import="java.util.Hashtable,javax.naming.*,com.getronics.ejb.*" %>
            request: <%= request.getRequestURI()%><br>
            <%
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                            try {
                              final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
                              jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
                              final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
                              ICalculadoraLocal calculadora = (ICalculadoraLocal)context.lookup("java:app/ejb-0.0.0.0.0.1/CalculadoraBean!com.getronics.ejb.ICalculadoraLocal");
                              int suma = calculadora.suma(2,2);
                              System.out.println("suma: " + suma);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        };
                    }.start();
                    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

It throws a NameNotFoundException:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app/ejb-0.0.0.0.0.1/CalculadoraBean!com.getronics.ejb.ICalculadoraLocal
```

Any ideas on why can this happen?

Comment: The problem cause is somewhere else, not in the sniplets that you are showing us. I lookup classes via JNDI in Wildfly 18 without having problems neither inside nor outside threads. I would recommend to list the content of the whole JNDI context then you see what's inside.

Comment: Err, no. **All** JNDI lookups are run inside threads.

Comment: You should check my example, and see how possible can "impossible causes" be.

Comment: Your answer proves my point. It has nothing to do with threading, and everything to do with `app` *versus* `global`. I'm baffled why you would want to run this code in a separate thread in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using "global" instead of "app" makes it work:

```
ICalculadoraLocal calculadora = (ICalculadoraLocal)context.lookup("java:global/ear-0.0.0.0.0.1/ejb-0.0.0.0.0.1/CalculadoraBean!com.getronics.ejb.ICalculadoraLocal");
```

The reason seems to be that JNDI lookup of "app", "module" and "comp" won't work in those threads as for specification.

You can check these links for more info:

[jndi lookup fails in user-thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/173179)

[[jboss-as7-dev] Issue with access to java:comp/UserTransaction from non EE threads](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-as7-dev/2011-June/002292.html)

Comment: Tangentially, the only official-looking documentation found was this: "Portable JNDI syntax" [here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/ejb-intro004.html#GIRGN) - with notes on the differences between `global`, `module` and `app`. But it's all in the context of EJBs from 10+ years ago.